# Launch and autopopulate an email from Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to click a button in Excel and launch an email, then automatically fill in various fields based on Excel's cell values.

The email looks roughly like this:

"Dear [name],

Job: [description]

Payment: [amount]"

...Etc. The information in square brackets is contained in my Excel spreadsheet, so I essentially want to  automatically have it copy and paste into the fields of the email.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Mail for Mac, Excel Mac 2011.

Comment: Not to be rude, but what have you tried so far? If I google "excel vba generate email", there are at least a dozen high-quality tutorials on exactly what you want (not to mention the many Stack Overflow questions that have already been asked and answered, ex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122747/send-email-from-excel-in-exchange-environment)

Comment: Fair question. The issue I'm running up against is that most tutorials are either for sending emails automatically (I don't want to SEND the email until I have customized it; I just want to autopopulate certain fields), or the tutorial is for Outlook, not Mail (which seems to be the case in the link you provide, although I am definitely a beginner when it comes to VBA, so I could be wrong). Thanks.

Comment: Looks like Mail does not integrate with Excel out of the box (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111110/create-new-mail-on-mac-using-excel-vba), so you'll probably need to do some pretty heavy coding/scripting to get something working. This site seems to have some examples of what you're looking for: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/macmail/macoutlook2016.htm

Comment: Thought as much. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: try to use "mailto: " | generate the link using concatenate/hyperlink function in excel, then click on it. ref : https://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/ (point number 5)